# rename directories padded with zeros using bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to rename a large number of directories so that they are padded with zeros. I am trying to run the bash script in the directory `workingDir` containing the `viz` directory. In the `viz` directory, I have directories

`visit_dump.0001

 visit_dump.0005 
 visit_dump.11000 
 visit_dump.12000 
 visit_dump.504000`

How can I rename them to the following?

`visit_dump.000001

 visit_dump.000005 
 visit_dump.011000 
 visit_dump.012000 
 visit_dump.504000`

Also, I do not know if the directory with the largest extension, here being `504000` will have `6` digits or more or less.

Below is an attempt with very strange results ( I get the message `printf: 04800: invalid octal number`
 and it assigns completely the wrong extension to the directory. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
eulerDir=visit_dump

dataDir=viz

cd ./$dataDir

for eulerDirIter in $(ls -d $eulerDir.*); do
    number=$(echo $eulerDirIter |awk -F . '{print $NF}')
    $(mv $eulerDirIter $(printf $eulerDir.%06d $number));
done
```

Comment: `rename 's/\.(\d+)$/sprintf ".%06d", $1/e' viz/*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finds the largest numeric extension in the first line, and handles each number as decimal not octal:

```
max=$(for f in *; do echo "${f##*.}"; done | sort -n | tail -1)
for f in *; do
    base=${f%.*}
    ext=${f##*.}
    newext=$(printf "%0*d" ${#max} "$((10#$ext))")
    echo mv "$f" "$base.$newext"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this hack:

```
awk -F . '{print $NF+0}'
```

The issue was that any number that starts with a `0` is treated as octal. So while `0005` in octal is the same as `5` decimal, a string like `04800` is treated as octal but unfortunately contains an `8` which makes it an illegal octal number.

You use `awk -F . '{print $NF}'` to get at the numerical suffix of the directories, but you want to treat them as numbers, so a simple way to convert the string `04800` to a number is to simple add `0` to it. (`awk` does not treat `04800` as octal).